# Failure to find artefact SLF4J when including it in a maven project that uses jmeter plugin with maria-db connect included

Tags: maven, jmeter-maven-plugin

The jmx file uses a JSR223 sample to run some selenium code and at some point it needs to connect to a maria database to get a code.

pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>kp-load-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                <execution>
                    <id>configuration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>configure</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>results</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jmeterExtensions>
                    <artifact>com.codeborne:selenide:5.7.0</artifact>
                    <artifact>org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.4.0</artifact>
                </jmeterExtensions>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Running the following command : mvn clean verify    throws the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.1.0:configure (configuration) on project kp-load-test: Failure to find org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:[1.4.0,1.7.25] in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-nexus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

If i comment the mariadb artifact from jmeterExtensions, the code selenium code will run and throw a driver exception when it reaches the jdbc part.

Looking in the mariadb jar i found the pom contained the following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>[1.4.0,1.7.25]</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

How can I pass mariadb artefact without generating that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to add
`<downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>`
Afterwards i added each library needed for the script to run

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/maven-jmeter-plugin-users/bf_uWS2TqXU